# Handle a SLIME/Swank error in Elisp

Tags: elisp, slime

Is it possible to handle a SLIME/Swank error in Emacs Lisp?

For example, suppose I have a Lisp buffer with a syntax error in it. How can I do something like:

```el
(condition-case nil
        (slime-eval-buffer)
      (error (message "Slime error")))
```

To handle the SLIME error?